# Error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Menu extends StatelessWidget {
  const Menu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    return Drawer(
      width: 200,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text(
              'MENU',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          _MenuItem(
            title: 'Accounts',
            color: color,
            icon: Icons.account_balance,
            onTap: () => onNavigate(context, '/accounts'),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          _MenuItem(
            title: 'Budget Items',
            color: color,
            icon: Icons.attach_money,
            onTap: () => onNavigate(context, '/items'),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          _MenuItem(
            title: 'Types',
            color: color,
            icon: Icons.widgets,
            onTap: () => onNavigate(context, '/types'),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onNavigate(BuildContext context, String uri) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(uri);
  }
  //This function serves two purposes: it pops the menu off the navigation stack. That way, when we come back to the home screen, the menu is not showing. It also pushes the new name route onto the stack.
}

class _MenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MenuItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.color,
    required this.title,
    required this.icon,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final Color color;
  final IconData icon;
  final Function onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      //Inkwell widget allow us to add a touch event handler to the child widget
      onTap: onTap, //gives error on this line.
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: 0.6,
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Icon(
                icon,
                color: color,
                size: 50,
              ),
              Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: color,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

kindly help. I'm receiving this error in Inkwell widget body, in onTap property, I created a final function variable OnTap, made it required and created a function OnNavigate that all menu items will call when tapped. But I'm getting this error. I've tried to change onTap to OnTap,ontap but doesn't works.

OnNavigate function serves two purposes: it pops the menu off the navigation stack. That way, when we come back to the home screen, the menu is not showing. It also pushes the new name route onto the stack.

Answer (score 1):

replace `final Function onTap;` with

```dart
 final VoidCallback onTap;
```

Comment: it works, what does it do? I am new to dart. also final Function() onTap worked for me too.

Comment: onTap doesn't return anything, it is described as `void onTap` 
and `funftion` is a abstract class , you can do like `void Function()? onTap;` You can check the duplicate for more details

Answer (score 1):

Please change this final `Function onTap;` to `final Function() onTap;` inside class `_MenuItem`

Comment: hi it worked, tysm, but why it worked can you elaborate a bit? I'm new to dart.

Comment: as you are calling this way : () => onNavigate(context, '/items'),  means you have to accept it   like this : final Function() onTap;

Comment: tysm! it means alot.